# R shiny: Run in Window (R Studio) does not Save or Print the datatable using TableTools Extension

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, tabletools

I am trying to use the TableTools extension for DataTables to get a toolbar with copy, save, print and other options above a table in my Shiny App.

This is my server.R:

```
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(datasetInput(),extensions = 'TableTools',options = list(
      "sDom" = 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
      "oTableTools" = list(
        "sSwfPath" = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables-tabletools/2.1.5/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf",
        "aButtons" = list(
          "copy",
          "print",
          list("sExtends" = "collection",
               "sButtonText" = "Save",
               "aButtons" = c("csv","xls")
          ))
        )
      ))
  })
```

This is the output:
[image]

As you can see, there is no copy button. Also, when I click on the Save button, a tiny bar appears below it and the screen goes gray but nothing happens next.

[image]

This only happens when I try to run the app using `Run in Window` (R Studio). If I run it as `External` in Chrome, then there are no issues. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please follow the documentation: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html Your `sSwfPath` points to another web server, and Flash may not work in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Yihui. I deployed my app on the server & it works. I read somwhere that this is a known issue with RStudio.

Comment: Okay, I see your edit. That makes it clearer. Yes, the RStudio preview window may not work well with Flash. You need to open the app in an external web browser.